# space issue between footer item and right arrow icon

Tags: html, css

I have a footer timeline. There are multiple items and left arrow and right arrow to scroll left side/ right side. While testing the responsiveness, If screen width > 1067 px then those left/ right arrow will not be visible as per application nature.

But, if screen width < 1067px and > 768 px then space between last item of footer container and right arrow icon is bigger than expected.

Here is the problem:
[image: space issue between right arrow and footer item]

For this, i have set up the media query based on screen resolution.

**Css**

```
    // bigger screen no arrows
        @media screen and (max-width: 1224px) {
      .footerContainer {
        .footer_outer_wrapper {
          .arrows {
            display: none;
          }
          .footer_inner_wrapper {
            height: 100%;
            .footer {
              .item {
                width: rem(75);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

   // ipad type screen having problem in right arrow
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and(max-width: 1062px) {
      .footerContainer {
        .footer_outer_wrapper {
          .arrows {
            display: block;
            .right-arrow {
              transform: translate(10%, -50%);
            }
          }
          .footer_inner_wrapper {
            margin-left: 36px;
            margin-right: 36px;
            width: rem(475) !important;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How to fix the space problem between right arrow and footer item?

Answer (score 1):

Try using "display:inline-block" instead of "display:block".

Comment: I had to put "display:inline-block" inside child class (.right-arrow) ... Otherwise it was not working...